# Opening and editing multiple files in a folder with python

Tags: python, edit, biopython

I am trying to modify my .fasta files from this:

```
>YP_009208724.1 hypothetical protein ADP65_00072 [Achromobacter phage phiAxp-3]
MSNVLLKQ...

>YP_009220341.1 terminase large subunit [Achromobacter phage phiAxp-1]
MRTPSKSE...

>YP_009226430.1 DNA packaging protein [Achromobacter phage phiAxp-2]
MMNSDAVI...
```

to this:

```
>Achromobacter phage phiAxp-3
MSNVLLKQ...

>Achromobacter phage phiAxp-1
MRTPSKSE...

>Achromobacter phage phiAxp-2
MMNSDAVI...
```

Now, I've already have a script that can do it to a single file:

```
with open('Achromobacter.fasta', 'r') as fasta_file:
    out_file = open('./fastas3/Achromobacter.fasta', 'w')
    for line in fasta_file:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if '[' in line:
            line = line.split('[')[-1]
            out_file.write('>' + line[:-1] + "\n")
        else:
            out_file.write(str(line) + "\n")
```

but I can't get to automate the process for all 120 files in my folder.

I tried using glob.glob, but I can't seem to make it work:

```
import glob

for fasta_file in glob.glob('*.fasta'):
    outfile = open('./fastas3/'+fasta_file, 'w')
    with open(fasta_file, 'r'):
        for line in fasta_file:
            line = line.rstrip()
            if '[' in line:
                line2 = line.split('[')[-1]
                outfile.write('>' + line2[:-1] + "\n")
            else:
                outfile.write(str(line) + "\n")
```

it gives me this output:

```
A
c
i
n
e
t
o
b
a
c
t
e
r
.
f
a
s
t
a
```

I managed to get a list of all files in the folder, but can't open certain files using the object on the list.

```
import os


file_list = []
for file in os.listdir("./fastas2/"):
    if file.endswith(".fasta"):
        file_list.append(file)
```

Comment: In the second code snippet, you are iterating the file name, not the file: `for line in fasta_file`.  You need to give the file object a name in the `with` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you are able to change the contents of file name now you need to automate the process. We changed the function for one file by removing file handler which was used twice for the opening of file.

```
def file_changer(filename):
    data_to_put = ''
    with open(filename, 'r+') as fasta_file:
        for line in fasta_file.readlines():
            line = line.rstrip()
            if '[' in line:
                line = line.split('[')[-1]
                data_to_put += '>' + str(line[:-1]) + "\n"
            else:
                data_to_put += str(line) + "\n"
        fasta_file.write(data_to_put) 
        fasta_file.close()
```

Now we need to iterate over all your files. So lets use `glob` module for it

```
import glob
for file in glob.glob('*.fasta'):
    file_changer(file)
```

Comment: I've got this error: `TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, type found`

Comment: @tahunami in which line ?

Comment: `line 20, in <module>  file_changer(file)` and `line 5, in file_changer
    with open(filename, 'w') as fasta_file:`

Comment: @tahunami Check it now .

Comment: yeah, it works, thanks. Although it does the editing on the same input files and I wanted to make new ones, to save the originals, but it's a minor thing

Comment: one question though: in `def` I have `file_changer(filename)` and that argument is used in the definition's code, but when I call it I use:  `file_changer(file)`. Does this mean that the argument filename was changed to file, which is basically my fasta files' names?

Comment: @tahunami `filename` acts as the argument variable in file_changer function scope. In the forloop for calling that function variable `file` is essentially providing the argument i.e. filename to the function `file_changer`

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating the file name, which gives you all the characters in the name instead of the lines of the file.  Here is a corrected version of the code:

```
import glob

for fasta_file_name in glob.glob('*.fasta'):
    with open(fasta_file_name, 'r') as fasta_file, \
            open('./fastas3/' + fasta_file_name, 'w') as outfile:
        for line in fasta_file:
            line = line.rstrip()
            if '[' in line:
                line2 = line.split('[')[-1]
                outfile.write('>' + line2[:-1] + "\n")
            else:
                outfile.write(str(line) + "\n")
```

As an alternative to the Python script, you can simply use `sed` from the command line:

```
sed -i 's/^>.*\[\(.*\)\].*$/>\1/' *.fasta
```

This will modify all files in place, so consider copying them first.

Comment: Can you tell me something more about the syntax of this line:
`with open(fasta_file_name, 'r') as fasta_file, \
            open('./fastas3/' + fasta_file_name, 'w') as outfile:`

Comment: @tahunami All files should be opened in a `with` statement to make sure they get properly closed.  You can open more than one file in a single `with` statement, and the back slash is just for line continuation.